# Running time of this Program

Tags: algorithm-analysis

```
def f(n):
 i = 2
 while i < n:
  print(i)
  i = i * i
```

I evaluated an expression that becomes something like 2^n or 2^2^n and set that equal to when the loop breaks or (2^2^n ) (>=)n    but can't figure out how to get a runtime. Can someone show how to do complete this analysis and get a runtime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)

Answer (score 4):

In the loop, $i$ is repeatedly squared so it will take the values
$$
2, 2^2=4, 4^2=16, 16^2=258, \dotsc
$$
In other words, $i$ will be
$$
2^1, 2^2, 2^4, 2^8, \dots,2^{2^k}
$$
so the loop will iterate $k$ times, until $2^{2^k}\ge n$. Taking the log of this inequality twice we'll have $k\ge \log \log n$ for our running time.